# member access into incomplete type ‘QScrollBar’

Tags: qt

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->width();
```

Im trying to get the width of verticalScrollBar of QScrollArea.
So I ran the code above and I got “member access into incomplete type QScrollBar error”.
What did I do wrong? and How can i get the width of verticalScrollBar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to `#include <QScrollBar>` because `verticalScrollBar()` returns a `QScrollBar*` and you de-reference that pointer and call `width()`, for that to work you need to include `QScrollBar` header file.